# In decimal expansion of real number, why the number of digits at the left side of decimal point is finite?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

I know the decimal expansion of a real number can be written as:

> $r=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{N}a_{i}10^{i}$

The question is why it has the upper limit $N$ of the summation? Why instead, we write a real number as

> $r=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{i}10^{i}$

I understand that if the series (at the right side) is infinite in both direction, it can not be convergent and can not be deal with, so as an infinite big real number.

Besides above consideration, is there any rule comes from the definition of real number forbid $N\rightarrow\infty$? Or, is it really necessary to define a real number to be a one we can deal with by current tool?

Comment: I can't say I understand exactly what your question is. What exactly do you want to know? What bothers you, since you have already answered yourself that if $N$ is infinite then it cannot be a *real* number?

Comment: Since you apparently believe such numbers exist, perhaps you can give an example of a real number in which the number of digits to the left of the decimal point is infinite. You don't have to write it out as a decimal numeral. Something like $\arctan( 3.85) - e^{201}$ would be fine, or describing the number as the solution to some algebraic or transcendental equation that can't be written in some reasonable explicit form like $\arctan( 3.85) - e^{201}$ would be fine.

Comment: @Allawonder my question is, if $N$ is infinite, it is true that we can not deal with it. But it can not forbid we to define it as a real number. Initially, real number is the set of rational number and irrational number; and irrational number is that can not be given by rational number. From this sense, the number Infinite $N$  can be treated as irrational number, should still be a real number.

Comment: *the number Infinite* $N$ *can be treated as irrational number, should still be a real number* --- This makes no sense. Instead of [waxing philosophically](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-be-waxing-philosophical), simply give an example of such a number.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Not all the real number can be written, even when $N$ is finite. What you mean is the *computable real number*, which can be given by **a set of *finite* process**. But it is already shown that, there exists many real numbers can not be given by finite steps, i.e. you can not write them out even $N$ is finite.

Comment: Usual definition of real number implies it is finite.

Comment: Do you know that the real numbers form an [Archimedian field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)?

Comment: @Xliu You *can* write any real number as $r=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{i}10^{i}$ as long as there's some integer $n$ where $a_i = 0$ for all $i \ge n$, i.e., you treat the number as having an infinite number of digits of $0$ on the left.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Based on the current definition, yes. I just dont understand when we give this constraint on real number and why?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes. It is true. But my question is can we have infinite nonzero $a_i$ for $i>n$, is this kind of number still a real number?

Comment: @Xliu, you may define such numbers, but you cannot call them real. No real number is infinite in magnitude.

Comment: @Allawonder Thank you. based on what consideration, we give this constraint - real number must have finite magnitude?

Comment: A reminder that the problems we want to solve come first and the definitions useful to solve the problems we want come after.  It so happens that the types of questions that we wanted to solve were such that when defining the real numbers, for example in problems about distance or limits, they were defined in such a way as to have that property that all real numbers would be finite in magnitude.  That does not stop us from generalizing the real numbers into something else which does allow for infinite magnitude elements.  See [p-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: @Xliu, exactly. This is usually referred to as the Archimedean property of the real field.

Comment: @JMoravitz Based on limits and distance, it is reasonable. If we refer "real numbers as all the points on an infinitely long line"  (just like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number says), do we still need real number to have a finite magnitude?

Comment: To be called a *number*, no.  To be called a *real* number, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know whether the following helps, but, just dealing with positive numbers first:

Step 1: Every integer has a representation as a finite decimal.
I think you can grant this, it’s what you did in the very first years of schooling.

Step 2: Every real number between $0$ and $1$ has a representation as a decimal, extending potentially infinitely to the right.
(The fact that some reals have two different-looking representations need not bother us.)

It’s one of the properties of the real number system that if $\lambda>0$ is a real, there is an integer $n$ with $n\le\lambda<n+1$. This is the Archimedean property of the reals, mentioned by several of the commenters. If a system does not have this property, then it certainly is not the system of real numbers.

Step 3: Now take any positive real number $\lambda$, find that integer $n$ mentioned just above, and represent $n$ by a finite decimal expansion (Step 1), and represent $\lambda-n$ as a potentially infinite expansion (Step 2). Put the two expansions together, and get your decimal expansion of $\lambda$.

As several others have said, the fact that this procedure doesn’t give you an infinite string of digits to the left comes from Archimedes.

---

**But**: I would be remiss if I did not mention that there is a self-consistent system in which there *are* decimal expansions going infinitely to the left. They do not go infinitely to the right as well, however. This system is called the “$10$-adic numbers”, and it is of relatively minor interest for mathematicians. If, on the other hand, you write your integers in base $p$, where $p$ is a prime number, and allow the expansions to go infinitely to the left (still forbidding infinitely many digits to the right), you get the $p$-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_p$, which are of extremely great interest in more advanced number theory. But that is a story for another day.

Comment: Thanks. Almost clear. Just to be curious.  If we refer "real numbers as all the points on an infinitely long line" (just like en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number says), is the points on an infinitely long line necessarily have the Archimedean property? Can we prove that? Or we just suppose that?

Comment: The assumption about the total line is that you can walk to and beyond any given point by taking 1-meter paces. If your line is longer than that ($*$), it’s not the real-number line. ($*$) There is something called “the long line”, which you’ll have to read about. It is associated with the first uncountable ordinal number. Please remember that we have a certain number of defining properties of the reals (“axioms”) which we use so that we know what we are talking about when we say “real number system”.